# WPF Listview item highlight by their first character

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listview and it binds customer datas from database. I want to be focused by their first character. For example, when I click on to "B" from keyboard then, highlight focus must go to customers whose names' first character is "B". Do you have any idea? My listview's XAML is below.

```
<ListView x:Name="datalist" ButtonBase.Click="datalist_Click" ContextMenuOpening="datalist_ContextMenuOpening" MouseDoubleClick="datalist_MouseDoubleClick" SelectionChanged="datalist_SelectionChanged"
MouseUp="datalist_MouseUp" PreviewMouseUp="datalist_PreviewMouseUp" >
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/235203/WPF-Highlight-ListView-items OR http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/409275/Highlight-Searched-Text-in-WPF-ListView

Comment: @Sandeep I will not use a textbox. I just want to type on the keyboard. Not into the anywhere..

Comment: Just to know more, if you're not intending to use a textbox, what will you do if you want to cancel the typed keyword? Will you just press a "Backspace" and assume that the previously typed character has been pulled out from the search algorithm?

Comment: @Sandeep I just want to make it like that. When we sign in to somewhere and while we are choosing the country then we type our country's first letter. So, we can find it easily. I just want to do something like that in my listview..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/409275/Highlight-Searched-Text-in-WPF-ListView) and instead of the textbox _TextChanged event use the Window_Keydown event to capture the Key pressed.

Instead of this:

```
private void textboxsearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FilterItems(listPerson, textBoxSearch.Text);
}
```

Use this:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    FilterItems(listPerson, e.Key.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the ListView gots focus, you can Attach an Behavior to the Listview like this:

(`System.Windows.Interactivity` needs to be referenced)
Xaml:

```
<ListView SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListViewItem>A Company 1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A Company 2</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>A Company 3</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>B Company 1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>B Company 2</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>C Company 1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>C Company 2</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>C Company 3</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>D Company 1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>D Company 2</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>E Company 1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>F Company 1</ListViewItem>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ListBoxHighlighting:ListViewBehavior />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </ListView>
```

Behavior:

```
 public class ListViewBehavior : Behavior<ListView>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.KeyDown -= OnKeyDown;
        }

        private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var key = e.Key.ToString();

            AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Clear();

            foreach (var item in AssociatedObject.Items)
            {
                var i = (item as ListViewItem).Content;
                if(i.ToString().StartsWith(key))
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```